# How to deliver value from popup.js to background.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-api

I hope to deliver the value from popup.js to background.js so that I can open the website as what i expect. I use the localStorage variable as my json's value. But when found that the value I have delieverd to background.js in the argument **input** of the function **openTab(input)** is always the string *"localStorage.input"*  itself. How can I solve it?

popup.js

```
window.onload=function()
{
    localStorage.input=document.getElementById("search").value；

    document.getElementById("submit").onclick=function()
    {
        chrome.extension.sendMessage({command:"start",input:localStorage.input});
    }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request,sender,sendResponse)
    {
        switch(request.command)
        {
            case "start":
                openTab(request.input);
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
);

var openTab=function(input)
{
    chrome.windows.create
    (
        {
            url:"http://www.baidu.com/s?wd="+input,
        }

    );
};
```

Comment: are you sure you want to override the localstorage value with an empty input on window.load()?

Comment: You are mixing up `extension.sendMessage` and `runtime.onMessage`, you might want to avoid that. (Use `runtime.sendMessage`)

Comment: Sorry I have changed my funtion and using **runtime.sendMessage**, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, but how are you expecting it to work? Your code will not send the actual value of the search field, only the one that exists on window load (probably empty).

Comment: It works finally. I made mistake in my popup.html. But still thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
var lStore = localStorage.input || '';
window.onload=function()
{
    var search = document.getElementById("search");
    search.value = lStore

    document.getElementById("submit").onclick=function()
    {
        // var input = search.value; //try this as well
        var input = lStore;
        chrome.extension.sendMessage({command:"start",input:input});
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have tried it out. But it still can't work. And I found that the value of **input** in the background.js has nothing.

Comment: did you also try `input = search.value` -- the commented one?

Comment: Thank you! It runs successfully! And I found that the problem is my localStorage. I made mistake with it in my popup.html :)